# MySQL/PHP broadcast message system

Tags: mysql, count, message, broadcast

I'm working on a messaging system where one aspect of it is for me to broadcast a message to all users. Instead of inserting the message into the table for each user, I have one table that contains a single copy of the message and another table that tracks user read/delete.

**Messages Table**

```
message_id (primary,auto)  
dt  
message
```

**Messages_Status Table**

```
message_id (int,11)  
user_id (int,10,indexed)  
user_read (tint,1)  
user_delete (tint,1)  
--> an index on (message_id,user_id)
```

I'm trying to get the count of unread messages for the logged in user. If there is no record in the messages_status table for that particular message and user (the user has not read it) or if there is a record for that message and user where user_read=0, that counts as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(m.message_id)
messages m
left outer join messages_status ms on ms.message_id = m.message_id
where user_id = 123
and (ms.message_id is null or ms.user_read = 0)
```

Comment: Since records do not exist initially in the status table, the where user_id=123 won't be found for a count. I've also tried where ms.message_id IS NULL OR (ms.user_id=123 AND ms.user_read=0), but as soon as a different user marks the message as flagged a record for that message_id is entered into the status table causing the ms.message_id IS NULL statement to be invalid.